# Quelle est la phrase la mieux tournée?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Je suis ton abonné *Meta Quest* et toi, le mien.

> Je suis abonné à ton compte *Meta Quest* et toi au mien.

> Je suis abonné à ton compte *Meta Quest* et réciproquement.

> Nous sommes mutuellement abonnés à nos comptes *Meta Quest*.

Auriez-vous des propositions de tournures d’un autre style et de meilleure langue à me suggérer?

Amis et followers
Les amis Oculus sont désormais des followers Meta Horizon. Vous continuerez de voir la section Amis sur votre appareil, mais ces amis sont vos followers réciproques (les personnes que vous suivez et qui suivent aussi votre compte). N’oubliez pas que seuls les followers réciproques sont visibles. Vous ne pouvez pas voir les personnes qui sont abonnées à votre compte lorsque votre profil est public. Découvrez comment contrôler qui peut voir votre activité dans la VR.
Vous ne pourrez plus ajouter d’autres utilisateurs en tant qu’amis dans votre casque, même lorsque vous sélectionnez Ajouter un(e) ami(e).
Pour approuver les demandes de suivi :
1.  Ouvrez l’application mobile Oculus sur votre téléphone.
2.  Appuyez sur Menu en bas à droite, puis sur Personnes.
3.  Sous Demandes de suivi, appuyez sur Confirmer.
Blocage
Vous pouvez retirer des amis ou bloquer d’autres utilisateurs dans la VR. Si vous retirez un(e) ami(e), l’abonnement sera à sens unique. Les utilisateurs retirés de la liste d’amis ou bloqués ne peuvent plus être débloqués ni ajoutés en tant qu’amis.

Comment: *le mieux tournée -- qualifies the genderless adverb, not the noun.

Comment: « la mieux tournée » est correct, pas « le ».

Comment: j'ai supprimé ma réponse à cause d'un flicage ... après vos précisions, la tournure a priori la plus claire est «nous nous suivons mutuellement sur les réseaux sociaux/Oculus» ou « nous nous suivons l'un et l'autre».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les phrases 2 et 4 sont les plus claires, la 3 l'est presque autant. Seule la première demande un peu d'effort de compréhension.

Voici d'autres suggestions:

> On est chacun abonné au compte Meta Quest de l'autre.
> Nous sommes abonnés l'un l'autre sur Meta Quest.
> Chacun d'entre nous est abonné au compte Meta Quest de l'autre.

Answer (score 1):

La première phrase semble suggérer qu'il y a un unique abonné pour chaque compte. Dans le cas d'un réseau social, on ne dirait jamais "je suis ton abonné", ni même, en fait, "je suis l'un de tes abonnés" (il y a là une idée de verticalité qui n'est pas commune lorsque l'on parle des réseaux sociaux).

La deuxième phrase peut être corrigée en enlevant "à", et mieux rythmée en ajoutant une virgule : "je suis abonné à ton compte, et toi au mien". C'est la tournure que je jugerais la plus légère et la plus élégante.

Les deux suivantes sont correctes, mais un peu lourdes et pas très modernes (ce qui contraste avec le sujet abordé).

Comment: Merci, auriez-vous des reformulations à me proposer?

Comment: "Nous sommes chacun abonné au compte de l'autre", ou effectivement "Je suis abonné à ton compte, et toi au mien".