# Accord de l'article défini pour un adverbe au superlatif

Tags: genre, superlatifs

> [Quelle est la phrase la mieux tournée?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51284)

In a comment on this question, I wrote that it should be ***le***, but I was myself corrected.

My understanding was that adverbial phrases in the superlative are genderless, and that this was an adverbial phrase.

This sort of comparison was given to me as a learner as an example of a clear-cut case:

> Elle est **la** plus rapide : elle court **le** plus vite.

Can you help me distinguish the case in question from this sort of example? I can certainly see that *tourné(e)* could be read as an adjective, but can't it be thought of as analogous to such phrases as

> He sent the hastily written letter by post the next morning

in which "hastily" clearly qualifies "written" adverbially? Or am I on the wrong path to an explanation?

Comment: I'd say *le plus vite* qualifies the action: *courir*, which is not explicitly mentioned, but clearly implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clear-cut explanation you gave makes the most sense here - "tournée" is not an adverb while "vite" is.

Your last remark points to what would happen if the sentence were

> la lettre la plus hâtivement écrite

vs

> la lettre le plus hâtivement écrite

but the original question is definitely a different, simpler case.

Note though that according to [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=3225403200;r=1;nat=;sol=0;), the article can stay invariable (~genderless) to emphasize the level of excellence of something relatively to an ideal. But it is not mandatory.

*mieux* II.A.1.b):

> Rem. 1. Lorsque le mieux précède un part./adj. au fém. ou au plur.,
> l'art. peut rester inv. s'il s'agit d'insister sur un degré
> d'excellence atteint par rapport à la notion qu'exprime le part. ou
> l'adj., plutôt que sur les êtres ou les choses comparés entre eux.
>
> *Les intrigues le mieux concertées, quoique tissues avec tout l'art et
> l'expérience possible, ont quelquefois, des suites fâcheuses (BOURGES,
> Crépusc. dieux, 1884, p.253)*

Comment: *makes the most sense?* / *makes the more sense?* A similar dilemma :D

Comment: *Quoique **tissues** avec* peut surprendre aujourd'hui.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key is that "*tournée*" is a participle acting as an **adjective** (it would be the same with an adjective), while "*vite*" is an **adverb**. Because of *mieux* and *plus* they're both adverbial phrases but they're fundamentally different.

I can't think of an example with an adjective but no agreement, or with an adverb and an agreement.

It makes sense because an adverb qualifies a verb, which has no inherent gender. Whereas an adjective or past participle will always qualify the subject.

And as LPH pointed out there can also be locutions, which could have an exception (I say *could* because I haven't found an example yet but I can't rule it out) but should always be invariable.

Comment: That's what I figure, too, but I find it hard to accept that the participle *must* be interpreted as an adjective. ... Then again, I've drafted this comment three times and still can't find a good reason why it seems that way to me. Moreover, if I align the comparison, even « la lettre la plus hâtivement écrite » seems clearly correct to me, which gives the lie to my instinct about *tournée* ...

Answer (score 1):

The "genderless" characterization seems irrelevant and the nature of "la mieux tournée" as  an adverbial phrase not right (unless I misunderstood what you meant).

> **(LBU  § 988)** **Observations sur le superlatif relatif**.
> **a)** [...]   **N. B.** L'article reste invariable quand *le plus, le moins, le mieux* se rapportent à un verbe, à un adverbe ou à une locution adverbiale.
>
> - *C'est elle qui **travaille** LE mieux.*  [userLPH: verb]
> - *Ceux qui sont venus LE plus **souvent**.*   [userLPH: adverb]
> - *C'est nous qui partons LE plus **à regret**.*   [userLPH: locution]

According to this rule for "le mieux", "le plus", and "le  moins", the adverbial phrase is determining as a complement of these three basic superlative forms; in "la phrase la mieux tournée", the word "tournée"  is simply an  adjective (although also  a past participle), and "la mieux tournée" a superlative adjective qualifying "la phrase" ("se rapporte"); but  when a verb is modified, that verb is a conjugated verb (first example: "travaille"). "La" must be  correct then.

---

*Addition  of the basic rule found at section **988**  of LBU*
*(The plentiful  examples found under that   heading should help to drive the idea home. Formating   and numbers in  the  reference due to  user LPH)*

> **LBU section 988** **Observations sur le superlatif relatif**.
> **a)**
> **Dans l'usage soigné, l'article du superlatif relatif d'un adjectif reste invariable quand il y a comparaison entre les différents degrés d'une qualité, quand l'être ou l'objet sont comparés avec eux-mêmes, spécialement dans des moments ou des lieux distincts.**
>
> - (1) *C'est au milieu de ses enfants qu'une mère est LE plus heureuse* (= heureuse
>   au plus haut degré).
> - (2) *C'est en motocross que les Belges sont LE plus forts* (ils sont
>   plus forts en motocross que dans les autres sports).
> - (3) *A partir du front, endroit
>   où la blessure a été LE plus dangereuse* (LAUTRÉAMONT, Mald., p. 83).
>   >- (4) *Les hommes ne se séparent de rien sans regret, et même les lieux, les choses et les gens qui les rendirent LE plus malheureux, ils ne les abandonnent point sans douleur* (APOLLIN., Flâneur des deux rives, p. 17).
> - (5) *Ce n'est pas que [...] la princesse des Laumes n'eût souhaité [...] de se montrer LE plus aimable possible* (PROUST, Rech.,
>   t, I, p. 330).
> - (6) *C'était de ce côté que les lapins étaient LE plus nombreux* (GENE-
>   VOIX, Raboliot, III, 6 ) .
> - (7) *C'est souvent lorsqu'elle est LE plus désagréable à entendre qu'une vérité est LE plus utile à dire* (GIDE, Journal, 5 juillet 1944).).
> - (8) *Le matin, à l'heure où les enfants sont LE plus légers* (BOSCO, Mas Théotime, p. 14).
> - (9) *C'est alors que la ville est LE plus étrange* (CURTIS, Étage noble, p. 41).
> - (10) *Où donc la vieillesse est-elle LE plus atroce ? Quand on y est comme ces gens de l'hospice ?*
>   (Gabr. ROY, Ces enfants de ma vie, p. 53.)
> - (11) *L'époque [..,] où Marguerite était LE PLUS nerveuse* (SIMENON, Chat, V).
> - (12) *Le domaine où le changement, la rupture et le refus des corrélations mécaniques sont LE plus profonds, c'est [... ] celui de
>   la politique étrangère* (Cl. ROY, dans le Nouvel Observateur, 5 sept. 1981).
>
> **Dans ce cas, la phrase contient souvent quelque indication marquant la
> circonstance (temps, lieu, etc.) qui coïncide avec le degré extrême de la qualité
> considérée.**
>
> **Mais l'article s'accorde avec le nom exprimé ou sous-entendu
> lorsqu'on fait la comparaison entre des êtres ou des objets différents.**
>
> - (13) *Cette femme est LA plus heureuse des mères, la mère LA plus heureuse* (elle est comparée aux autres mères)
> - (14) *C'est en motocross que les Belges sont LES plus forts* (ils sont plus forts que les concurrents des autres pays).
> - (15) *Les questions qui paraissent LES plus dangereuses se trouvent un jour résolues par les circonstances* (MAUROIS, Mes songes que voici, p. 217).
> - (16) *Dans l'exil général, ils étaient  LES plus exilés* (CAMUS, Peste, p. 88).

*Translations  and remarks*

> **Dans l'usage soigné, l'article du superlatif relatif d'un adjectif reste invariable quand il y a comparaison entre les différents degrés d'une qualité, quand l'être ou l'objet sont comparés avec eux-mêmes, spécialement dans des moments ou des lieux distincts.**
> **Mais l'article s'accorde avec le nom exprimé ou sous-entendu
> lorsqu'on fait la comparaison entre des êtres ou des objets différents.**
>
> > *In careful style, the article of the relative superlative of an  adjective is invariable when the comparison is made  between the various degrees of a characteristic, when the  being or object  is compared with itself.*
> > *However, there is agreement of the article with the explicitly  written   or  ellipted noun  when the comparison is made between various beings or objects.*

In other words when the various degrees of a characteristic are compared as pertaining all to a single being or object  having this  characteristic, those degrees being acknowledged  at different  times or places, then the agreement of the article is necessary, however,  this is so not only as relates to time  or place,  but as well for situations neither related  to particular times or places.

- De tous les poèmes  qu'elle avait  écrits dans son enfance  c'était d'un  poème sur  les oiseaux  qu'elle   était le  plus heureuse.(*There are such  cases  in LBU's examples (2,5)*)

When the various degrees are acknowledged as pertaining to two or more beings or objects, so that  the characeristic is being  compared over various beings or  objects,there must be agreement.

Compare carefully "1" with "13"  and  "2" with "14".

In conclusion, it could  be  said that the rule is ill applied  in the spoken language quite often, transgressed in the literature not so unfrequently, and that there are certain intricacies  that have not been mentioned in  the foregoing, but that  this basic principle still takes care of a lot of cases.

Comment: The follow-up question, then, would be whether you could ever conceive of a passive past participle as consistent with this kind of adverbial phrase (or, more to the point, whether one could ever be genderless in the superlative).

Comment: @LukeSawczak  It seems to me  that the idea  of  genderlessness has no incidence on the  decision  for the adjective/participle. All  that is  determining is the  rule  concerning the comparison (which  I thought  you knew for its essential part (or I  would have added  it): stated roughly, comparison of the  degrees over  several beings makes agreement  necessary, comparison over a single  being makes  for  agreement  (genderlessess)).  So the genderlessness of the phrase has no meaning and in  the case  of  modification of  a noun ("la phrase ... tournée") there is no adverbial  phrase.